# AngularJS app MVC4 bundling brakes app

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a big angularJS app which is inside ASP.NET MVC,
When i include scripts one by one using script tag everything works without any issues but as soon as i enable bundling and minification through web.optimization some controllers does not get resolved and app brakes.

```
            var scriptBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundle/app")
            .Include("~/App/app.js")
            .IncludeDirectory("~/App", "*.js", true);
```

This is how i register bundle. after doing this first thing i see in console after loading app is

```
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/nomod?p0=app
```

and ins some controllers i get following errors.

```
Argument 'ControllerName' is not a function, got undefined
```

this is very strange because when i look in loaded script this controller is controller is definitely loaded.

when declaring angularjs controller i use following pattern.

```
marketConfigWizardCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'close'];
angular.module('PcoreManager').controller('marketConfigWizardCtrl', marketConfigWizardCtrl);

function marketConfigWizardCtrl($scope, close){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this pattern?

```
var MyController = function($scope, greeter) {
  // ...
}
MyController.$inject = ['$scope', 'greeter'];
someModule.controller('MyController', MyController);
```

According to the docs:  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

> To allow the minifiers to rename the function parameters and still be
>   able to inject the right services, the function needs to be annotated
>   with the $inject property. The $inject property is an array of service
>   names to inject.

Comment: Yes i did but it did not work. the reasons is during minification and bundling it generates script in a order where controllers are defined in a bottom of the response and this is real problem. the only way i can make it work is to list all includes manually which is really not a good way as this is enterprise app and there are too many scripts.